# How to disable or enable button from different page

Tags: php

How to `disable/enable` button from admin page with PHP [php](/questions/tagged/php).

```
page1 = button

admin page = disable / enable button in page 1
```

So we have a different page ( **2 page** ) .

```
page1 and admin page .
```

How to `disable/enable` that button from admin page?

The point is just want disable and enable button from admin page ( **2 diffrent page** )

```
<input type="submit"
       name="tebak"
       value="&nbsp;&nbsp;TEBAK SCORE&nbsp;&nbsp;"
       class="btn default"/>
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Store the info ( whether the button is enabled or disabled ) in database.

Answer (score 0):

Webpages are stateless. Do you mean control the state of a button using xmlHttpRequest? The long and short of it is if you add the attribute disabled=“disabled” to the input tag, the button is disabled. However you need to have server-side scripting because disabling the button only prevents someone from submitting a form (or toggling a button) through a browser interface. Someone could still use CURL for instance, to programmatically submit a post to the url that processes your form submittal.

You can also control button enablement and disablement using JavaScript.

Comment: can u give me a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag in SQL. If Flag true then don't print a href-"" in the button an set the CSS to grey

ELSE

Load the button like usual

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help? (NOT TESTED)

```
session_start();


$_SESSION["button_status"] = "disable";

if ($_SESSION["button_status"] = "disable"){
?>
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
<?php
}else{
?>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<?php
}
```

**Reference sites:**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: It was 'not tested', it was just a demo/example to give you a direction that you may be able to use, may also need to set this up on both pages, and I also suspect you may need to sort the sessions out in your php.ini or test that it actually is working. Do a phpinfo(); on your web server.